# react native - problem with useState, fetch value?

Tags: react-native

I want to update the 'people' field. The problem is that the previous value goes to the state, not the current one. I don't know how to make it correct.

I am getting a value from previous rendering

```
const [totalPeoplem, setTotalPeople] = useState(0);

const handleUpdate = async (initialItem) => {

firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('city')
    .doc(itemId)
    .update({
    people: totalPeople
     }).then(() => {
      console.log('Update');

     });

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it with `useEffect`

For example:

```js
const [totalPeoplem, setTotalPeople] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  const handleUpdate = async (initialItem) => {
    await firestore()
      .collection('users')
      .doc(user.uid)
      .collection('city')
      .doc(itemId)
      .update({
        people: totalPeoplem,
      }).then(() => {
        console.log('Update');
      });
  };
  handleUpdate()
}, [totalPeoplem]);
```

Comment: OK. Thanks, that's what I was after.

Comment: good, it is an answer please mark it.